# App engine 500 server error on serializing a class in shared package of a GWT project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a Friend class in shared folder. Which is the type of ArrayList returned by RPC. On uploading the project first time I got the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.aman.gwt.friendlist.shared.Friend' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.aman.gwt.friendlist.shared.Friend@6cffbb
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:665)
```

So to solve the issue I imported java.io.Serializable, implemented it and declared

```
private static final long serialVersionUID=-3195362485601524606L;
```

But now I am getting 500 server error on app engine. I checked the log but nothing is there.

Update: It was a temporary problem.Occurs sometimes on updating the application.

Comment: Which error ? Please provide useful information in your question.

Comment: Make sure friend has a no argument constructor. Also make sure all classes that friend uses are available to gwt and are serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Is the *source code* for your `Friend` class (and any own classes `Friend` uses!) available in the artifact - missing that usually causes errors like this. Another possible cause is getting something wrong or missing `<inherits ...` or `<source ...` in the .gwt.xml descriptor.

Cheers,